# Get registered Service of AutoFac from within a filter/messagehandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

This is done within a AuthorizationFilterAttribute class:

```
var service = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IOurService);
```

vs

```
var requstScope = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
var service = (IOurService)requstScope.GetService(typeof(IOurService));
```

What is the concrete difference and its side effects?

Hint: `actionContext.ControllerContext.Request vs actionContext.Request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decompile `HttpActionContext` you will see that the `Request` property is implemented like this :

```
public HttpRequestMessage Request
{
    get
    {
        if (this._controllerContext == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return this._controllerContext.Request;
    }
}
```

So both of your code are completely equivalent.